# assigning variables using "var" or no keyword

Tags: javascript

```
(function foo() { var a=b=c=1 }())
```

When I try to log a will return a not defined err, however, when I try to log b or c will return the value 1. It's wicked.

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Comment: Always use strict mode to prevent mistakes like this from happening. `(function foo() { "use strict"; var a=b=c=1 }())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> however, when I try to log b or c will return the value 1.

Because you didn't localized the scope (inside the function)  of `b` and `c` by using `var` or `let` or `const`.

Without `var`, `let` or `const`, these variable will take the **scope in which this function is defined**.

If the outer scope (not outermost) also doesn't localize those variables, then parent scope is checked again till the outermost scope (`window`). And the variable gets added to outermost scope if no local scope is defined for them. for example

```js
function a() {
  (function foo() {
    var a = b = c = 1;
  }());
  console.log(b, c); //print 1,1
}
a();
console.log(b, c); //print 1,1
```

However, if these variables are defined in outer scope, then they don't get added to the outermost (`window`) scope. For example, following will throw an error.

```js
function a() {
  var b,c;
  (function foo() {
    var a = b = c = 1;
  }());
  a();
  console.log(b, c); 
}
console.log(b, c);
```

Comment: 'scope in which this function is specified' described clearly. I thought the leading var has confined the scope of those three variables.

Comment: No, leading `var` is only for a since you are using an assignment expression. You meant `var a = 1, b = 1`?

Comment: @BlakeWoo Also, I meant **defined**, rather than *specified*. I have made the changes.

Comment: Yes,  I didn't realize assignment expression is operating like this.

Comment: @BlakeWoo ohh, is your question/doubt answered now?

Comment: Yes, but I still feel this is weird, this make me no more want use assignment expression in this format.

Comment: @BlakeWoo  It's not the assignment that's the problem, but the var declaration.  if you had done `var a,b,c; a=b=c=0`; it would have been fine.

Comment: You shouldn't be since you are likely to pollute the global scope, though unintentionally.

Comment: @BlakeWoo If you can use new ES6 features, and you have lots of code that wants these sorts initialised data constructs,. there is a neater way.

Comment: @Keith I think this may be a weird processing way with js interpreter.

Comment: @BlakeWoo It is not weird or confusing, this is the intended behavior. Since you didn't associated `var` with a variable, its scope didn't get localized.

Answer (score 4):

`b` and `c` are added into the window object and get their values as `1`. But `a` is declared via `var`. This means that `a` is visible only in the function context and not outside from it.

Your code is equivalent

```
(function foo() { 
   c = 1;
   b = c;
   var a = b;
}())
```

Comment: Thanks. I will guess the js interpreter will do this under the scene.Still it kind of weird.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of constructs where you want to initialise to some constants and you can use ES6 features the following is a nice way to do it.

```js
//store function in your lib
function* initVar(value) {
  while (true) yield value;
}

//using function
let 
  [a,b,c] = initVar(0),
  [d,e,f] = initVar("xyz"); //not just limited to numbers.

console.log(a,b,c,d,e,f);
```